# Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name

Tags: perl

I'm new with Perl, and I've faced this problem:

```
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @str"?) at F:\Distrib\LingUtils9\Scripts\CompareLists\CompareLists.pl line 167
```

A piece of code, that causes this message, works as a programm, but does not work as a sub. Here it is:

```
 my $containsSub = 0;
my $str = "This is a string!";
my $substr = "string";
my $indexOfSub = index($str, $substr);
if ($indexOfSub != -1)
{
    if (length($substr)==length($str))
    {
            $containsSub = 1;
    }
    elsif (($indexOfSub == 0)&&(($str[$indexOfSub + length($substr)]=='?')||($str[$indexOfSub + length($substr)]=='!')||($str[$indexOfSub + length($substr)]=='.')||($str[$indexOfSub + length($substr)]==' ')||($str[$indexOfSub + length($substr)]=='\t')))
    {
            $containsSub = 1;
    }
    elsif ((length($str) == $indexOfSub + length($substr))&&(($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='.')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]==' ')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='\t')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='?')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='.')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='!')))
    {
            $containsSub = 1;
    }
    elsif ((($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='?')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='!')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='.')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]==' ')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='\t'))||(($str[$indexOfSub+length($substr)]=='?')||($str[$indexOfSub+length($substr)]=='!')||($str[$indexOfSub+length($substr)]=='.')||($str[$indexOfSub+length($substr)]==' ')||($str[$indexOfSub+length($substr)]=='\t')))
    {
            $containsSub = 1;
    }
}
print $containsSub;
```

It is very primitive verification of the contents of the subline in line, and it works fine. But this (just copypaste):

```
sub containsKey 
{
    my $containsSub = 0;
    my $str = "This is a string!";
    my $substr = "string";
    my $indexOfSub = index($str, $substr);
    if ($indexOfSub != -1)
    {
        if (length($substr)==length($str))
        {
            $containsSub = 1;
        }
        elsif (($indexOfSub == 0)&&(($str[$indexOfSub + length($substr)]=='?')||($str[$indexOfSub + length($substr)]=='!')||($str[$indexOfSub + length($substr)]=='.')||($str[$indexOfSub + length($substr)]==' ')||($str[$indexOfSub + length($substr)]=='\t')))
        {
            $containsSub = 1;
        }
        elsif ((length($str) == $indexOfSub + length($substr))&&(($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='.')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]==' ')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='\t')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='?')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='.')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='!')))
        {
            $containsSub = 1;
        }
        elsif ((($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='?')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='!')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='.')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]==' ')||($str[$indexOfSub-1]=='\t'))||(($str[$indexOfSub+length($substr)]=='?')||($str[$indexOfSub+length($substr)]=='!')||($str[$indexOfSub+length($substr)]=='.')||($str[$indexOfSub+length($substr)]==' ')||($str[$indexOfSub+length($substr)]=='\t')))
        {
            $containsSub = 1;
        }
    }
    return $containsSub;
}
my $keyContains = containsKey();

print $keyContains;
```

makes this output in command line

```
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 16
3.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 16
3.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 16
3.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 16
3.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 16
3.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 16
7.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 16
7.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 16
7.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 16
7.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 16
7.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 16
7.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 17
1.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 17
1.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 17
1.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 17
1.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 17
1.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 17
1.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 17
1.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 17
1.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 17
1.
Global symbol "@str" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "
my @str"?) at \Compare.pl line 17
1.
Execution of \Compare.pl aborted
due to compilation errors.
```

And I just can't understand what can it be.

Comment: The code implicitly uses `@str`, by doing `$str[$indexOfSub...]`.  Clearly, the program and how the sub are used aren't the same, perhaps by having `use strict;` in whatever drives the sub.  Please add `use strict;` and declare everything.  And _absolutely_ `use warings;`.

Comment: zdim, thank you :) your answer was not a solution, but it made this issue clearer. I've added use scrict, caught the same error in program. Now I understood that my code was incorrect syntactically (I incorrectly addressed letters of the line), so it was required to replace it with it only

Comment: so it was required to replace `$str[$indexOfSub + length($substr)]=='?'`  with `substr($str, $indexOfSub + length($substr), 1)=='?'` only

Comment: Yep, got it after I saw Sobrique's answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because perl strings aren't arrays of characters like they are in some languages.

Thus `$str[3]` is not a valid way of accessing `$str`. But rather, it would access the 3rd element of `@str` which doesn't exist and hasn't been declared, hence the warnings.

If you wish to work with strings by offset, then you need `substr`. Or `my @chars_in_str = split //, $str;`

More broadly though - this looks like a rather filthy way to try and regex match.

I'd suggest what you *actually* want to do is:

```
if ( $str =~ m/\b$substr\b/ ) { 
    $containsSub = 1;
}
```

`\b` is perl-regex for 'word boundary', and so will match things with punctuation or spaces, although it's not *strictly* equivalent to what you're doing (there's a whole bunch more punctuation that'll 'work').

You should also note - if `$substr` contains meta characters, they'll work like regex modifiers. To avoid that, you'd need `\b\Q$substr\E\b` which turns off metachar processing.

Comment: Ah, a nice catch :)

Comment: YES! Yes it is :) Thank you very much

Comment: `$containsSub = $str =~ m/\b\Q$substr\E\b/`